# Install programs like Apple do

Tags: software-installation

Why not let us install programs the same way Apple do? One file and thats it and if one wants to uninstall, just delete the file/folder.

Comment: How *do* you currently install applications for Ubuntu? Because software for Ubuntu comes bundled in *one file* typically a `.deb`

Comment: sometimes you have to download the source, and then you get it in tar.gz or zip which isn't that great.

Comment: @dajomu I think the way we install software in ubuntu is great, in the way that, because of it's "difficulty", it prevents some sort of mistaken and installation of malicious software.

Comment: @Alvar, what on earth is wrong with source files in tar.gz?

Comment: @dajomu, The way we do it currently is way better/easier. Everything we need is in the repository, we never have to go manually download anything. What exactly is better about the apple approach. Just that you're used to it?

Comment: If anything, Apple is moving in the direction of Linux systems with its App Store for Mac.  Pick your software from a central catalogue, and have updates for all your software handled by a single service.

Comment: Is 'just delete a file' what is really happening, or is it a misleading metapher, misleading in that there are different things happening behind the scene? In Synaptic, there are different ways to remove an installed program: remove and purge - one is keeping the settings, afaik, and the other removes all. Apple isn't acting that transparently, but more in a 'works like magic'-way, while the Linux-approach is more, to show you, how it works.

Comment: -1 for being a subjective question. Seems this might do better on http://ubuntuforums.org or a mailing list.

Comment: @user it's not a deb!

Comment: @Alvar: Sorry, but what is no a deb?

Comment: tar.gz is not a deb! :)

Comment: This **suggestion** doesn't belong here. Suggestions should be posted on http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ and discussions can be had on the forums.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu uses an installation system based off of Debian, which is to use .deb packages.  These packages contain instructions for installing and removing software from the system.

This system is controlled via `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, or the Synaptic Package Manager GUI (a front-end for `apt-get` and `dpkg`).  Installation is as simple as specifying what package(s) to install, and removal is similar.

There is also a Software center in Ubuntu.  This software center is for the less-tech-savvy user, but has the same results as my aforementioned methods for managing packages.  With the Software Center, too, you don't need to know all the package names, you only need to know the software's name, and it can usually find it (if its in the repositories).

Comment: +1 : what @The Evil Phoenix is basically saying is that this is effectively the same as the way Apple does it. One file - point and click if you want.

Comment: If you don't agree with an answer leave a comment and downvote - then right your own answer.